# How to append php into an unordered list?

Tags: php, list, unordered

Hello how do you add php into an unordered list like below ?

```html
<?php // Render the Category List
 categoriesList(); ?>
<?php
```

into

```html
<ul  class="oi_smalldev_categories_list">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-7">
        <a href="category/coding/index.html" title="This extended category features articles on client-side and server-side programming languages, tools, frameworks and libraries, as well as back-end issues. Experts and professionals reveal their coding tips, tricks and ideas.">Coding</a>
    </ul>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please precise your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to take the results from the function and add them to your unordered list.

Basically, in your function you can create a string that is the HTML you want to output. In this case multiple

tags.

You can then store it in a variable and call it with PHP further down the page.
Not the best way to handle it but I think this can do what you're after.

So, here's some pseudo code to handle that.

```
<?php // Render the Category List
$results = categoriesList(); 
?>

function categoriesList(){
return '<li>'.'category1'.'</li>'.'<li>'.'category2'.'</li>'.'<li>'.'category3'.'</li>';
}


<ul  class="oi_smalldev_categories_list">
<?php echo $results; ?>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<ul>    
<?php
   $mycats = categoriesList();
   foreach ($mycats as $cat) {
     echo '<li>'. $cat. '</li>';
   }
?>
</ul>
```